# Python3 model_inspector

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, random-forest, python-3.9, python-3.10

I am in a data science class and we are learning about RandomForectRegressor.

Part of the code makes a call to import get_inspector. Previously, when I did this, I had no errors but I recenetly installed reinstalled anaconda3 and now it isnt working. I am getting this error below:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model_inspector'. The last part of the code below is what is causing the issue.

I am running python 3.9.13 on this computer and python 3.10 on my laptop. Neither are working.

Any ideas?

Here is the code up until this point in the jupyterlab file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns



hitters = pd.read_csv("../assets/data/hitters.csv").dropna()
hitters = pd.get_dummies(
    hitters, columns=["League", "Division", "NewLeague"], drop_first=True
)

X = hitters[hitters.columns[~hitters.columns.str.startswith("C")].drop("Salary")]
y = hitters.Salary



from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, GridSearchCV

grid = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1, random_state=1),
    param_grid={"n_estimators": range(10, 600, 50)},
    cv=KFold(5, shuffle=True, random_state=1),
    scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error",
    return_train_score=True,
)
grid.fit(X, y)



from model_inspector import get_inspector

ax = get_inspector(grid, X, y).plot_scores_vs_hparam()
```